# NodeJS Requested data leaks across HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, webserver

I have a simple webserver created in Express.js. The server serves files that are dynamically created by processing data from a third-party API.

Here is my webserver code, it requests `builder.js` to build the file, which requests, receives, processes and returns data from a third-party API by `await`ing the response of a promisified oauth request as needed. The builder will at least call the API two or more times to create a complete file ready for serving.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const builder = require('./builder.js');
let requestID = 0;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    requestID++;
    console.log(`tab: ${requestID}<`);
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8')
    res.status(200).send('Hello World');
    console.log(`tab: ${requestID}>`);
});

app.get('/file', async function (req, res) {
    requestID++;
    console.log(`tab: ${requestID}<`);

    if (req.query["id"] != undefined) {
        let URLparams = new URLSearchParams(req.query);

        console.log(`tab: ${requestID}, requested id: ${URLparams.get("id")}`);

        let output = await builder.buildFile(URLparams);
        try {
                console.log(`tab: ${requestID}, requested id: ${URLparams.get("q")}, served ${getIDfromOutput(output)}`);

                res.set('Content-Type', 'application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8')
                res.status(200).send(output);
            
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(`tab: ${requestID}, ${e}`);
            if (e instanceof String) { res.send(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(e), null, 3)); }
            else { res.send(JSON.stringify(e, null, 3)); }
        };
    } else {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8')
        res.status(404)
        .send("404: Page not found.");
    }
    console.log(`tab: ${requestID}>`);
});

app.listen(3000, "localhost");
```

The code works as intended when making requests to the `/file` one at a time.

```
//1 tab loaded
tab: 1<
tab: 1, requested: 1331444331778101248
tab: 1, requested: 1331444331778101248, loaded 1331444331778101248
tab: 1>
```

However, when the endpoint is requested for multiple *unique* requests at the same time (opening multiple tabs at the same time or running parallel `wget` commands), the server either responds correctly in some cases, but it mostly responds with the same file served previously.

```
// 5 unique tabs loaded at the same time: 1551641441679597569, 1448115610173558787, 1370689539505860613, 1328121208022446086, 1509637745140019212
tab: 1<
tab: 1, requested: 1551641441679597569
tab: 2<
tab: 2, requested: 1448115610173558787
tab: 2, requested: 1551641441679597569, loaded 1551641441679597569
tab: 2>
tab: 3<
tab: 3, requested: 1370689539505860613
tab: 3, requested: 1448115610173558787, loaded 1448115610173558787
tab: 3>
tab: 3, requested: 1370689539505860613, loaded 1370689539505860613
tab: 3>
```

The result of these simultaneous requests causes tabs 1-4 load fine, but tab 5 shows the output of tab 4. The console logger can't also seem to show the issue, but it's definitely different to the normal, one-off request.

I do not want this to happen as I fear that this may happen in production, and I do not want the outputs to be leaked across requests. However, I have no idea what is causing this or how to investigate to fix this issue. The code works fine when builder.buildFile() has to make one API call to the third-party, but I am always making 2 or more calls.

---

As requested, here is the stripped version of the `buildFile` function. When serving directly from the API through `builder.getData(url)`, the responses for each request is unique and the responses do not cross over other requests. It happens only when it goes through `builer.buildFile()`. I feel like the issue is with the way the promises are handles, but I am not sure.

```js
const OAuth = require('oauth');
const { promisify } = require('util');
require('dotenv').config();

let oauth = getOAuth();

module.exports = {

    buildFile: async function (urlParam) { //URLSearchParams(req.query)

        let id = urlParam.get("id");

            try {
                let metadata = await getData(`http://API/id=${id}?type=metadata`);

                let XMLFile = await fileBuilder(metadata);
                return XMLFile;

            } catch (e) {
                console.log("Err: ");
                console.log(e);
                return Promise.reject(e);
            }
    },

    getData: async function (url) {
        return await getData(url);
    }

}

async function fileBuilder(metadata) {
    let response = await getData(`$http://API/id=${id}?type=fulldata`);
    response = extendData(response); //calls await getData() once more to fill in any gaps in the initial response
    let xml = ``; 
    /* Build XMl file as a string, appending as the function processes the data*/
    return xml;
}

function getOAuth() {
    return new OAuth.OAuth(
        'https://API/request_token',
        'https://API/access_token',
        process.env.api_key,
        process.env.api_secret,
        '1.0A', null, 'HMAC-SHA1'
    );
}

async function getData(url) {

    const get = promisify(oauth.get.bind(oauth));

    let body;
    try {
        body = await get(
            url,
            process.env.access_key,
            process.env.access_secret
        );
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("getData failed: \n" + JSON.stringify(e));
        return Promise.reject(e);
    }
    return JSON.parse(body);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the buildFile function? It seems you have two distinct issues here, one is the console.log that you see mixed up and the other is the files not being served as you expect. The console.log issue is simple to fix but the files not served is probably in the buildFile function and not in this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see the mixup in the console because you are using the shared `requestId` after it was changed. In order to avoid this you need to fix it at the beginning of the function.

The problem you have with the wrong file being served might come from the `buildFile` function since I can't locate it in this code fragment.

```
app.get('/file', async (req, res) => {
    const localReqId = requestID++;
    console.log(`tab: ${localReqId}<`);

    if (req.query.id !== undefined) {
        const URLparams = new URLSearchParams(req.query);

        console.log(`tab: ${localReqId}, requested id: ${URLparams.get('id')}`);

        const output = await builder.buildFile(URLparams);
        try {
            console.log(`tab: ${localReqId}, requested id: ${URLparams.get('q')}, served ${getIDfromOutput(output)}`);

            res.set('Content-Type', 'application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8');
            res.status(200).send(output);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(`tab: ${localReqId}, ${e}`);
            if (e instanceof String) {
                res.send(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(e), null, 3));
            } else {
                res.send(JSON.stringify(e, null, 3));
            }
        }
    } else {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
        res.status(404)
            .send('404: Page not found.');
    }
    console.log(`tab: ${localReqId}>`);
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! It was not an issue with `buildFile()` but with the my lack of using `const`s. I've updated the code to declare a const to ensure it does not get modified (both the `requestID` and `output`) and the issue is resolved!